# jquery - div not showing on checked radio option

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button, hide, show

I know there are several examples here about this issue, yet I cannot get it to work (newbie to jquery) and I'd appreciate any help.

```
<fieldset id="ctrl_529" class="radio_container mandatory">
<legend>Zertifizierungszyklus</legend>
     <input type="radio" name="certcycle" id="opt_529_0" class="radio" value="Erstzertifizierung" /> 
    <label id="lbl_529_0" for="opt_529_0">Erstzertifizierung</label>
    <input type="radio" name="certcycle" id="opt_529_1" class="radio" value="Rezertifizierung" /> 
    <label id="lbl_529_1" for="opt_529_1">Rezertifizierung</label>
</fieldset>

<div id="Rezertifizierung" class="addForm" style="display:none;">
<input type="text" name="nocert" id="ctrl_533" class="text halbeBreite" value="" maxlength="70" /><br />
<label for="ctrl_533" class="halbeBreite">Wievielte Rezertifizierung?</label>  
...
</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:radio[name='certcycle']").click(function() {      
        $('.addForm').hide();
        $('#' + $("input:radio[name='certcycle']:checked").val()).show();
    });
});
```

I want the div.addForm to be hidden onload or if the upper radio button is checked. Checking the second radio button is to show the div.

I've been trying all day with different snippets I found here, but my div won't react at all and I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: your form is hided on page load what is the wrong exactly

Comment: It works for what you've asked.

Comment: @user2917560: check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTQb8/) and explain what is wrong in there?

Comment: Wow - thanks to all of you. I don't know, it neither worked in jsfiddle last night nor in my web. Maybe it was plain too late for me ...

Comment: Well, what is working just fine on jsFiddle isn't working in my website. Firebug says

`TypeError: $(...) is null
$(document).ready(function ()
TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function
$(document).ready(function () {`
Can you help me with this?

Comment: I found the troublemaker: Mootools.